# How to run animations simultaniously?

Tags: android, svg, path

I have two animations and I want them to run simultaneously. One of them is an animation of an SVG path and the other one is just moving a view on the screen to another point.

I searched and I figured out that I could do it by using ObjectAnimator with PropertiesValuesHolder, but these do not offer the option to run an SVG path animation (I guess), so I can't use this because of the SVG animation.

Is there any way I can run them at the same time?

This is for versions of Android 5.0 or higher, using androidx libraries.

I expected the animations to run simultaneously, but after starting one after the other one, they just got crazy in the timing and looks weird sometimes.

Comment: You say "SVG", but I presume you are actually talking about VectorDrawables. Is that correct?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Handler class, Its like threads in java

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
     // enter you code to run your animations
           }
         });
```

You can make two handler classes and run your 2 animation simultaneously .